# 389-ds ldap - remove user from group

Tags: ldap, redhat, ldap-query

We have 389-ds directory with many users in a particular group. Does anyone know how I can delete a user from a group called ' clients ' using ldapmodify or ldapdelete command line tools?

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

Using ldapmodify:

```
ldapmodify -h ldapserver -D "cn=admin" -w password -f modGroup.ldif
```

where modGroup.ldif is:

```
dn: cn=clients, o=Your Company
changetype: modify
delete: member
member: cn=user1896576, o=Your Company
```

-jim